# What happens to the space station during a solar flare / magnetic storm?

Tags: radiation, space-station, solar-flares

What are the effects on the ISS during a solar flare / magnetic storm? The news often warns that satellites could be affected during a storm. Does the ISS have special protections for that danger?

Comment: Excellent, thank you. The mobile app search returned no results for "solar flare space station". I tried a couple others and got nowhere. Your links are useful!

Comment: @DanSorensen do you feel your question, or the question you'd like to ask is sufficiently answered there? If so, let people know. One way to do that would be to volunteering to vote to close yourself (that's certainly optional, I do it but many wouldn't). However if you feel there's something more you'd like to know, perhaps you could edit this question and further differentiate it from the Q & A there. I think that answer is lacking in specifics, so if there's something *specific* you would like to know, then perhaps you could zero-in on that?

Comment: @uhoh I didn't know enough about the topic to be more specific and was having trouble finding the right question in this site to learn more. That question answered my curiosity with its in depth answer. I'll vote to close. Thanks to @Dragongeek!

Comment: I think it would be interesting to ask if astronauts have ever experienced a substantial radiation dose on the ISS due to a particular solar event for example. I haven't researched that yet (and it's after midnight here) and "substantial" would have to be pinned down; perhaps relative to the integrated dose over a standard 5 or 6 month stay; like an additional 10% or double.

Comment: Good idea. It would need to be formulated better than this question I asked around midnight. A separate question that might need to be asked is if any electronics or support systems on-board have had any damage related to solar activity.